# System never prompts user for camera usage

Tags: ios, camera

Folks,

I am desperate for some feedback. I have been working on this for few days and no luck. I have an app that was released to App Store and was working prior to 9.0. The issue is the camera. When the user attempts to scan a barcode, he/she is promoted to allow camera use on device. With 9.0 this seems to be broken only on the older devices: 5s, 5c( some not all), mini iPad. As part of my debugging, I used the AVCam sample code from Apple and updated the app with it. AVCam compiled and loaded from Xcode 7 into the 5s, camera works. My app, with the AVCam camera code from the sample ( copied and pasted), compiled and loaded from Xcode 7, still never prompts the user for the camera allow. my iPhone 6 Plus works fine with all these iterations (user is prompted the first time). I feel it is something in the app environment since it was created by Xcode 5, then updated to Xcode 6, and now Xcode 7. But the question is where to look? By the way the camera status on the older devices starts with "not determined", and shows a black screen. when the user tries to use the camera again, at this point I see the camera status "denied". the prompt was never shown to the user, after every fresh install.

settings> privacy> camera shows that the app never requested for the camera. But I know this is not true: the code did request.

here is the sniper code that request the camera usage:

```
switch ( [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] )


{
    case AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
    {
        // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
        NSLog(@" ******* CAMERA USAGE AUTHORIZED FROM THE START ******* ");
        break;
    }
    case AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
    {
        // The user has not yet been presented with the option to grant video access.
        // We suspend the session queue to delay session setup until the access request has completed to avoid
        // asking the user for audio access if video access is denied.
        // Note that audio access will be implicitly requested when we create an AVCaptureDeviceInput for audio during session setup.
        NSLog(@"***** CAMERA STATUS NOT DETERMINED FROM THE START ***** ");
        dispatch_suspend( self.sessionQueue );
        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^( BOOL granted ) {
            NSLog(@" Do we now have permission %d", granted);
            if ( ! granted ) {
                self.setupResult = AVCamSetupResultCameraNotAuthorized;
            }
            dispatch_resume( self.sessionQueue );
        }];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        // The user has previously denied access.
        NSLog(@"**** CAMERA USAGE NOT AUTHORIZED FROM THE START **** ");
        self.setupResult = AVCamSetupResultCameraNotAuthorized;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's very little we can do without looking at some code. Please share snippets of how you're presenting and initialising the classes.

Comment: Can go into privacy settings and enable it there? If so, are you certain those devices hadn't denied permission previously?